# Proving weak coercivity by young's and interpolation inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let be
$$(P)\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
&-\Delta u + V(x)u=f & \text{ in }\ \Omega\\
&u=0 & \text{ on } \ \Gamma
\end{array}\right.$$
with $V \in L^r(\Omega)$, for some $1<r<\infty$. I want to prove weak coercivity. Im trying to acotate this using this two inequalities:

Interpolation inequaity ($1\leq p \leq q \leq r \leq \infty$ and $u \in L^p(\Omega)\bigcap L^r(\Omega)$)
$$||u||_{L^q(\Omega)}\leq ||u||_{L^p(\Omega)}^{\theta} ||u||_{L^p(\Omega)}^{1-\theta}  $$
And i suspect it could be very useful this one,

Young's inequality: $1<p,q<\infty$ and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$, then

$$ab \leq \epsilon a^p + C(\epsilon)b^q, \quad C(\epsilon)=(\epsilon p)^{-q/p} q^{-1}$$

so I could prove that $-\Delta  + V(x)$ leads a weak formulation in $H_0^1(\Omega)$.

I have been fighting with this for hours, but i don't get anything. Thanks!

I thought about gettin $p=1/\theta$, $q=1/(1-\theta)$, $a=||u||_{L^p}$...

Comment: What is the definition of weak coercivity ?

Comment: There exist a $\mu_0 : a_0(u,v)=a(u,v)+\mu_0<u,v>, u,v \in V$  is coercive

Comment: Don't you mean to use Lax-Milgram theorem ? If so, then you have a unique weak solution if $V(x)\ge0$ a.e in $\Omega$

Comment: In a book i have told to ue interpolation inequality. I think with youngs it must be easy if i get the right cote. I think with $p=1/\theta$ and so im near, its just i dont know which $\epsilon$ and so

Comment: But L-M need the hypothesis of weak coercivity

Comment: Maybe it will be better if you tell which book you are reading and on which page, because there is some context missing there.

Answer (score 0):

Your weak formulation is $\int\limits_{\Omega}{\nabla u\cdot\nabla vdx}+\int\limits_{\Omega}{Vuvdx}=\int\limits_{\Omega}{fvdx},\,\forall v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$. So if you denote $$a(u,v)=\int\limits_{\Omega}{\nabla u(x)\cdot\nabla v(x)dx}+\int\limits_{\Omega}{V(x)u(x)v(x)dx}$$ you have $$a(u,u)\ge C\|u\|_{H_0^1(\Omega)}+\int\limits_{\Omega}{Vu^2dx}\ge C\|u\|_{H_0^1(\Omega)}, \text{ if } V(x)\ge 0,\,a.e\,\, x\in \Omega\,\quad (*)$$
The constant $C$ comes from using Friedrich's inequality, and $(*)$ is the needed coercivity of the bilinear form, which you need in Lax-Milgram's theorem.

Comment: I know it sounds like an supid questino but im a bit saturated. This have some relationship with interpolatino and youngs inequaities? Thanks. Im told tu use it

Comment: No, this has no relation with interpolation and Young's inequality. This is a very basic thing to show that the bilinear form $a(. , .)$ is coercive. This is why I asked you what is the context, because it sounds like killing a fly with a gunshot.