# Greens first identity

Tags: finite-element-method, greens-function, greens-theorem

Good afternoon all.

Using the greens first identity I am finding weak formulation. Can someone check I did this correct with below mentioned greens first identity

$$\int_U (\nabla \cdot \nabla \mathbf{u}) \cdot \, \vec{\omega} \, dU = \int_{\partial U} \frac{\partial {\mathbf{u}}}{\partial n} \cdot \vec{\omega}\, dS - \int_U \nabla \mathbf{u} : \nabla \vec{\omega} \, dU  $$

[image]

[image]

My answer is :

[image]

Comment: I think you need to use the scalar Green's first identity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities

Comment: It is correct, but if you want to get a symmetric variational problem, then you should split the term $\alpha\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\alpha}{2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x\partial y}+\frac{\alpha}{2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y\partial x}=\frac{\alpha}{2}\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)+\frac{\alpha}{2}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)$

Comment: This means to write your initial PDE in divergence form (because $\alpha,\beta \in\mathbb R$ and so you can insert them in the derivatives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the equation:
$$-9u_{xx}-5u_{yy}=f$$
Now multiplying by a test function $v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ both sides and integrating over $\Omega$ you get.
$$-9\int\limits_{\Omega}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)vdxdy}-5\int\limits_{\Omega}{\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)vdxdy}=\int\limits_{\Omega}{fvdxdy}$$
$$9\int\limits_{\Omega}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}dxdy}+5\int\limits_{\Omega}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}dxdy}=\int\limits_{\Omega}{fvdxdy}\quad\quad (*)$$
which is the weak formulation that you should get.
We used $$-\int\limits_{\Omega}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)vdxdy}=-\int\limits_{\Omega}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}v\right)dxdy}+\int\limits_{\Omega}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}dxdy}=-\underbrace{\int\limits_{\partial\Omega}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}vn_1ds}}_{=0}+\int\limits_{\Omega}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}dxdy}=\int\limits_{\Omega}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}dxdy}$$
Here, the tool that we used is the divergence theorem (with which is actually derived the Green's first identity). Note that the surface integral is $0$ because $v$ is zero on $\partial \Omega$ (to be more speciffic, it is zero in the trace sense). Or if you want to avoid the use of the divergence formula in the weak sense, then you can start by multiplying by a smooth test function $v\in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$, derive the equation $(*)$ above, and then use density argument to show that $(*)$ is actually satisfied also for all $v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$. The integral with the $y$-derivative is done in similar way, just having in mind that in the surface integral there will be the second component $n_2$ of the normal vector $n$ to $\partial\Omega$ .

Comment: I understood the concept mentoined above, which is pretty much similar to integration by parts. I have confusion about the xy terms together if you can check with my updated question please

Comment: Yes, it is actually just integration by parts. I will check your solution and write here possibly in several hours.

Comment: I updated my solution

Comment: Here is another weak PDE http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653737/proving-weak-coercivity-by-youngs-and-interpolation-inequalities/1653763#1653763